# how to revoe and display objects fom Map

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm trying to write a program using a Map to map the details of an employee with the hobbies of the employee. The program should take the details of the employee and his/her hobbies as input and then store them as key/value pair in the map. Once the addition of details is complete, then the user should be able to list down all the employees, along with their hobbies and also should be able to view a particular employee's (by giving employee id as input), details and his/her hobbies . Also the user should be able to delete an employee based on the id of the employee.

I have tried as follows. But the method 'deleteEmployee()', 'isEmployeePresent()' and 'displayEmployees()' are erroneous

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Employee {
    String designation, name;
    Date dob;
    int employeeID;
    float salary;

    public Employee(String designation, Date dob, int employeeID, String name,
            float salary) {
        this.designation = designation;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public int getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public float getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public void setEmployeeID(int employeeID) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setSalary(float salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}

class Hobby {
    String hobbyDescription, hobbyName;

    public Hobby(String hobbyName, String hobbyDescription) {
        this.hobbyName = hobbyName;
        this.hobbyDescription = hobbyDescription;
    }

    public String getHobbyName() {
        return hobbyName;
    }

    public String getHobbyDescription() {
        return hobbyDescription;
    }

    public void setHobbyName() {
        this.hobbyName = hobbyName;
    }

    public void setHobbyDescription() {
        this.hobbyDescription = hobbyDescription;
    }
}

public class EmployeeManagement {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HashMap<Employee, Hobby> hm1 = new HashMap<Employee, Hobby>();
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many names do you want to add to the system? ");
        int w = sc1.nextInt();
        EmployeeManagement ob = new EmployeeManagement();
        ob.addEmployees(w, hm1);
        ob.displayEmployees(hm1);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("1. Delete an employee");
            System.out
                    .println("2. Check whether an employee is present or not");
            System.out.println("3. Break the loop and terminates the program");
            int ch = sc1.nextInt();
            switch (ch) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Enter Employee-I'd:");
                int p = sc1.nextInt();
                ob.deleteEmployee(p, hm1);
                ob.displayEmployees(hm1);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter Employee-I'd:");
                int q = sc1.nextInt();
                boolean b = ob.isEmployeePresent(q, hm1);
                if (b == true)
                    System.out.println("The employee is present");
                else
                    System.out.println("The employee is not present");
                break;
            case 3:
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void addEmployees(int n, Map<Employee, Hobby> abc) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Employee[] obj1 = new Employee[n];
        Hobby[] obj2 = new Hobby[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Employee name:");
            String nm = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter designation:");
            String des = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter employeeI-D:");
            int eId = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter salary:");
            double sl1 = sc.nextDouble();
            float sl = (float) sl1;
            System.out.println("Enter Hobby-name:");
            String hnm = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Hobby-description");
            String hdes = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Enter date-of-birth:");
            String dt1 = sc.next();
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            try {
                Date dt = formatter.parse(dt1);
                obj1[i] = new Employee(des, dt, eId, nm, sl);
                obj2[i] = new Hobby(hnm, hdes);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            abc.put(obj1[i], obj2[i]);
        }
    }

    public void deleteEmployee(int id, Map<Employee, Hobby> m1) {
        if (m1.containsKey((Employee.getEmployeeID()) == id))
            m1.remove(Employee);
    }

    public boolean isEmployeePresent(int id, Map<Employee, Hobby> m2) {
        if (m2.containsKey((Employee.getEmployeeID()) == id))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void displayEmployees(Map<Employee, Hobby> hm) {
        for (Map.Entry<Employee, Hobby> m : hm.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(m.getKey() + " " + m.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Erroneous ? In what sense ?

Comment: `containsKey(key)` etc. require the key you used for an entry, i.e. you need a key of type `Employee` here.

Answer (score 0):

You're triying to access `Employee` methods in a static way:

```
if(m1.containsKey((Employee.getEmployeeID())==id))
//                 ↑ here
```

You must get the instances of `Employee` inside the map and then compare with the id given:

```
public void deleteEmployee(int id,Map<Employee,Hobby> m1) {
    // iterate in the map searching for the id
    for (Entry<Employee, Hobby> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        Employee e = entry.getKey();   // here you have the employee
        Hobby h = entry.getValue();    // here you have the hobby

        // check if this employee have same id than given
        if(e.getEmployeeID() == id) { // map contains the employee
            m1.remove(e);
    }
}
```

NOTES:

- I would recommend to return a boolean to check if employee has been updated, deleted, etc...  `public boolean deleteEmployee(int id,Map<Employee,Hobby> m1)`
- I would keep the employees in another way, `HashMap` does not allow duplicates, so you cannot save more than one `Hobby` in each employee if you don't declare it like `HashMap<Employee, List<Hobby>>`.

Comment: What about displayEmployees(Map<Employee, Hobby> hm) ??
According to the code snippet i had given, it prints some arbitrary garbage values. I entered two employee ditails & this function shows as follows
Employee@6bc7c054 Hobby@232204a1
Employee@75b84c92 Hobby@4aa298b7

Comment: Garbage values?? It prints default `toString`... Just override toString or reference an attribute of the class like e.getName()

Comment: ok fine... solved this... but now problem arises with void deleteEmployee(int id, Map<Employee,Hobby> m1) function...
the function is now as follows :
public void deleteEmployee(int id,Map<Employee,Hobby> m1)
 {
     for (Map.Entry<Employee, Hobby> entry : m1.entrySet())
  {
   Employee e = entry.getKey();   
   Hobby h = entry.getValue();    
   if(e.getEmployeeID() == id)
   { 
    m1.remove(e);
   }
  }
 }

Comment: program compiles successfully... entries are also added in the map... but when i call this function, it throws following exceptions--
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(Unknown Source)
 at EmployeeManagement.deleteEmployee(EmployeeManagement.java:170)
 at EmployeeManagement.main(EmployeeManagement.java:113)